# Does any site keep track of how many pages each point of view character has in each book of ASoIaF?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire, online-resources

I'm rereading [*A Feast For Crows*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feast_For_Crows) (4th book in the [*A Song of Ice and Fire*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Song_of_Ice_and_Fire) series by [George R. R. Martin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_R._R._Martin)) and either [Cersei](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cersei_Lannister#Cersei_Lannister) has way more page time than any other character, or I just hate reading her so much that it *feels* like that's the case.

Without spending the time to count it out myself, I'm wondering if there is already a resource to answer this question for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I couldn't find one with page counts, but [here's a resource](http://www.lagardedenuit.com/wiki/index.php?title=PoV#Statistiques) with chapter counts. The page is in French, but key information is either English or international: character names, book titles, chapter counts, and charts (mmm, beautiful charts). Of course, chapters vary in length, so chapter counts are only a rough approximation — but it's a good start. And you're right, Cersei's ten chapters are more than anyone else's.

I found it via [this discussion](http://asoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/topic/45144-characters-by-pov-chapters/) in the forums at [asoiaf.westeros.org](http://asoiaf.westeros.org/), which I strongly recommend if you like ASoIaF.

Comment: Google chrome has the nice little 'This page is in French, would you like to translate it ...' functionality

Comment: A chapter count is MUCH better and overcomes my point in my response.

Comment: That's super-helpful, thanks sjl! Personally I'd still be curious to know page counts, so that I can get an idea of what percentage of my book is taken up by Cersei.  But until somebody can provide that, I'll accept this as the correct answer.

Comment: Jeff, I don't see a response from you. Did you delete it?

Comment: Surely you’d want a word count.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite, you're right, chapter count is just a rough answer. Word count might be best -- but page count would be much easier, and nobody has cared enough to mine page counts from the spreadsheet Justin links to in a comment to his answer. :(

Comment: And word count will track page count _very_ closely. For example, Bran's chapters might have more words per line than the average. He's a kid, so he'll tend to use shorter words. OTOH, his paragraphs will also be shorter, so his pages will have more partially-empty lines. 

Conversely, Tyrion's chapters might have fewer words per line, but fewer partially-empty lines. 

I doubt anyone's words per page will vary by more than 10% either way.

Comment: @sjl: sure, although page counts will differ between different print runs, right? If two books in the series use a different font or are printed at a different size, their respective counts wouldn’t be comparable. What I’m saying is that I think you should definitely start counting words now. Don’t worry — we’re happy to wait.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: Page counts will be -very consistent for a given title in a given format (e.g., US mass-market paperbacks of [AGoT](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?8656) are all 835-837 pages).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: Likewise, fonts and margins will be pretty consistent (again, same publisher, same format). Fortunately, we're not talking about Terry Pratchett's US paperbacks. You should start counting to prove me wrong. [wc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wc_%28Unix%29) is your friend. ;)

Comment: “Page counts will be -very consistent for a given title in a given format” — well yes. I was saying outside of that, they’ll differ. Oh I’m not nearly handsome or clever enough for a word count task like this, definitely more in your wheelhouse.

Comment: No, I won't count any higher than my fingers will let me, so [1023](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger_binary) is my limit. And that's not enough characters to [list everybody](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66717/is-there-a-table-of-all-deaths-in-a-song-of-ice-and-fire) GRRM has killed. So you'll have to count. Unless you can talk [someone else](http://muppet.wikia.com/wiki/Count_von_Count) into it ...

Answer (score 7):

[This post on `r/asoiaf`](http://www.reddit.com/r/asoiaf/comments/299qz9/spoilers_all_i_made_a_couple_of_charts_of_the_pov/) includes nice pie charts of *chapter* counts, which helps to roughly illustrate how much of each book is dedicated to each character:

[image]

Looks like Cersei did in fact get the largest slice for AFFC.

Comment: How correct are these? On the ADWD pie chart, it says that Arya has both 1 and 2 chapters

Comment: @Shevliaskovic - Good catch, from the linked discussion: `I think it was supposed to say Areo`. Arya has 2 chapters in ADWD and Areo has one.

Comment: Page counts could be mined from [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K8DJTFUUIZvQsgnkxv3d-142SXTcmnTV4YuHsNubHjA/htmlview?sle=true#gid=688707816) although I have not done so. Perhaps someone else is so inclined :)

Comment: If anyone is interested: http://www.reddit.com/r/asoiaf/comments/2g6gng/spoilers_adwd_analysis_of_chapter_lengths/

Comment: The problem with this is that chapter lengths are not the same in each book...

Comment: I suppose it would depend upon the format of book.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a link to some more graphs with distributions by the number of pages in a chapter for each character and various other information. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfQW7.jpg

The most relevant images are these:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Good find. Can you [edit] your answer to show the relevant graphs directly?

Comment: @curiousdannii I took the liberty of editing them in.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Thanks! I thought I did that, but apparently I did not!