# Is there a table of all deaths in A Song of Ice and Fire?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I realise this sounds like a software rec, but I don't think it is, I'm asking after a specific resource for one purpose, not general-purpose software.

Is there a comprehensive table of every single death that takes place in ASOIAF, preferably in spreadsheet, database or CSV format? A list would do as well, so long as it is exhaustive. Does anyone know of such a resource?

Comment: There is a [year by year list of events](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Years_after_Aegon%27s_Conquest) which may suit your needs. Though of course it does not account for unnamed people, and it might not include all minor characters.

Comment: I think they're in [here](http://www.google.ca/imgres?imgurl=&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.collegehumor.com%2Fpost%2F6894741%2Fall-my-friends-are-dead-in-game-of-thrones&h=0&w=0&tbnid=LObpx_tzl_moqM&zoom=1&tbnh=259&tbnw=194&docid=lMTS5L_K5Boc8M&tbm=isch&client=firefox-a&ei=a7IAVJWcMsaH8gHkjoG4CA&ved=0CAIQsCUoAA)

Comment: For what it's worth, [there is **now**](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nujtymy6/3/embedded/result/)! Why, yes; I *might* have had a few, uh, *minutes* (give-or-take...), to kill...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a list of all the deaths so far, courtesy of [a post on this thread](http://asoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/topic/47887-list-of-death/page-4) in A Forum of Ice and Fire. I added them directly in this answer so the list can be corrected if anyone sees any errors, but I think it is more or less complete. Hopefully it is not too much trouble for you to extract them:

Game of Thrones

> Ser Waymar Royce, Will, Gared, Lord Jon Arryn, Mycah, Lady, Ser Hugh Of The Vale, Jyk, Kurleket, Mohor, Morrec, Chiggen, Lharys, Heward, Wyl, Jory Cassel, Hali, Wallen, Stiv, Tregar, Ser Vardis Egen, Viserys Targaryen, King Robert Baratheon, Fat Tom, Varly, Cayn, Desmond, Hullen, Porther, Othor, Jafer Flowers, Lord Vance, Ser Raymun Darry, Masha Heddle, Ser Jaremy Rykker, Khal Ogo, Khal Fogo, Ulf Son Of Ulmar, Conn Son Of Coratt, Lord Halys Hornwood, Eddard Karstark, Torrhen Karstark, Daryn Hornwood, Quaro, Qotho, Haggo, Cohollo, Lord Eddard Stark, Septa Mordane, Vayon Poole, Rhaego, Eroeh, Khal Drogo, Lord Andros Brax, Mirri Maz Duur

A Clash of Kings

> Maester Cressen, Praed, Ser Burton Crakehall, Lord Lyman Darry, Barra, Allar Deem, Doreah, Woth, Dobber, Qyle, Murch, Koss, Gerren, Kurz, Reysen, Urreg, Yoren, Lommy Greenhands, King Renly Baratheon, Ser Robar Royce, Ser Emmon Cuy, Ser Stevron Frey, Ser Stafford Lannister, Chiswyck, Benfred Tallhart, Weese, High Septon (Fat One), Ser Preston Greenfield, Ser Aron Santagar, Alfyn Crowkiller, Ser Cortnay Penrose, Lord Leo Lefford, Lady Donella Hornwood, Alebelly, Mikken, Ser Amory Lorch, Septon Chayle, Drennan, Squint, Gelmarr The Grim, Aggar, Gynir Rednose, Farlen, Ser Imry Florent, Ser Mandon Moore, Lord Bryce Caron, Ser Guyard Morrigen, Maester Tothmure, Ser Rodrik, Cley Cerwyn, Leobald Tallhart, Red Rolfe, Kenned, Ulf, Black Lorren, Squire Dalbridge, Ebben, Qhorin Halfhand, Poxy Tym, Maester Luwin

A Storm of Swords

> Iggo, Ser Jacelyn Bywater, Allard Seaworth, Dale Seaworth, Matthos Seaworth, Maric Seaworth, Jate Blackberry, Lord Guncer Sunglass, Lord Chyttering, Hookface Will, Hal The Hog, Maslyn, Thoren Smallwood, Ser Ottyn Wythers, Small Paul, Ser Helman Tallhart, Tion Frey, Willem Lannister, Delp, Elwood, Lord Rickard Karstark, Lord Monford Velaryon, Kraznys mo Nakloz, Grazdan mo Ullhor, Ser Cleos Frey, Jarl, Symon Silvertongue, Brown Bernarr, Bannen, Craster, Garth Of Oldtown, Rolley Of Sisterton, Ser Byam Flint, Lord Commander Jeor Mormont, Alyn, Lord Hoster Tully, King Balon Greyjoy, Lord Sawane Botley, Kyle, Septon Utt, Bodger, Lark The Sisterman, Ryles, Chett, Softfoot, Prendahl na Ghezn, Sallor The Bald, Robin Flint, Ser Wendel Manderly, Lucas Blackwood, Donnel Locke, Owen Norrey, Ser Garse Goodbrook, Lady Dacey Mormont, Smalljon Umber, Aegon "Jinglebell" Frey, King Robb Stark, Ser Tytos Frey, Ser Raynald Westerling, Grey Wind, Deaf Dick Follard, Rast, Young Henly, Old Henly, Dornish Dilly, Magnar Styr, Quort, Stone Thumbs, Ygritte, Oznak zo Pahl, Mero, King Joffrey Lannister, Ser Dontos Hollard, Vargo Hoat, Donal Noye, Mag The Mighty, Ser Endrew Tarth, Ser Aladale Wynch, Red Alyn Of The Rosewood, Prince Oberyn Nymeros Martell, Orell, Harma The Dogshead, Polliver, The Tickler, Watt Of Longlake, Dalla, Shae, Lord Tywin Lannister, Lord Eon Hunter, Lysa Arryn, Petry Frey, Merrett Frey

A Feast For Crows

> Pate, Nimble Dick Crabb, Pyg, Timeon, Shagwell The Fool, Senelle, Ser Arys Oakheart, Marillion, Lord Baelor Blacktyde, Ser Talbert Serry, Ser Balman Byrch, Falyse Stokeworth, Dareon, Maester Aemon, Lady Tanda Stokeworth, Rorge, Biter, Lord Gyles Rosby, Lord Beric Dondarrion, Ser Ryman Frey

A Dance With Dragons

> Thistle, Varamyr Sixskins, Stalwart Shield, Hazzea, Janos Slynt, Dirk, Ollo Lophand, Clubfoot Karl, Lord Alester Florent, Kyra, Rattleshirt, Mossador, Ralf Kenning, Dagon Codd, Adrack Humble, Hagen The Horn, Rolfe The Dwarf, Quenton Greyjoy, Oppo, Black Jack Bulwer, Hairy Hal, Garth Greyfeather, Ser Jared Frey, Rhaegar Frey, Symond Frey, Lord Harwood Fell, Yellow Dick, Little Walder Frey, Luton, Holly, Barsena Blackhair, Yurkhaz zo Yunzak, Dormund, Torwynd The Tame, Hamish The Harper, Maester Kerwin, Nurse, Admiral Groleo, Yezzan zo Qaggaz, Cromm, Crunch, Khrazz, Rowan, Squirrel, Willow Witch-Eye, Frenya, Myrtle, Ser Patrek Of King's Mountain, Prince Quentyn Martell, Grand Maester Pycelle, Ser Kevan Lannister

Comment: Not really a mistake, but is there a reason Beric Dondarrion is listed in A Feast for Crows, when he died off-screen in SoS?

Comment: Probably because we don't [learn about his death](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Beric_Dondarrion#A_Feast_for_Crows) until AFFC.

Comment: Cobbled together from the information supplied in your answer: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nujtymy6/3/embedded/result/

Comment: It doesn't matter for my purposes when they died, all I need to know is up to the present point in the story, who is alive, dead or unknown. So this is great; thank you very much!